# Left side bigger than right side

Tags: push-ups, biceps, chest, triceps

I started doing serious push-ups in July (60 a day). It's been almost 4 months and I got good results. My chest, biceps, triceps have become bigger, much more defined.

However, my left side chest, bicep and tricep are noticeably bigger than the right side ones. I am right-handed and always favor the right side when working.

I don't understand how this happened. As far as I know I don' have any disease. The last time I was seriously sick it was the flu (last winter). Other than catching a cold from time to time, I have never been seriously sick.

Pleas help me understand!!

P.s.: I am forty.

Comment: _"I am right-handed and always favor the right side when working"_ - I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 2):

```
I am right-handed and always favor the right side when working.
```

That's pretty much the reason for the asymmetry in your body. In fact, most people have these kinds of issues when they train. Simply because our dominant hand tries to compensate for the weaker hand.

You can fix this by balancing the amount of work according to how much the difference there is between your muscles.

For e.g., in the bench press, use dumbbells instead of barbells and end your session with a few sets (1-2) with your weaker side. Repeat this until you feel symmetry in your body.